# JSTREE, dnd - making SQL database update with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, jstree

I have setup a hierarchical mysql table as follows (with example data) in laravel:

```
id | name   | parent_id
1  | test   | 0
2  | test 2 | 0
3  | test   | 2
```

I am displaying this data using JSTree with dnd and state plugins. The problem is that when you use dnd (which allows the list to be dragged/edited) to move the list objects around, the sql table also needs to be updated so that the edits are permanent and don't get lost on refresh.

I have no idea where to start on this? Does anyone have any tips or can help with a solution?

I believe I need to get the javascript actions interacting with laravel events/listeners such that it updates the sql table dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to somehow send the action to the server, which would normally be done using an ajax call. You would listen for the `move_node` event and then get the appropriate data that you need from the tree data. Here's some code that might help:

```
var treeData = {your tree data};
$($tree).jstree({
    core: {
        data: treeData,
        check_callback: function (op, node, parent, position, more) {
            switch (op) {
                case 'move_node':
                    return moveNode(node, parent, position, more);
                case 'copy_node':
                    return copyNode(node, parent, position, more);
            }
        },
        multiple: false
    },
    plugins: ['dnd']
}).on('copy_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
    $app.debug('copy_node completed', data);
}).on('move_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
    // this is where you connect to the server!
    doMoveNode(data);
});
```

Comment: ..Except that your code sends a move while DND is happening, for every single possible move encounter.  the server code would be good for validating a move - but not great for the actual move operation!